# is it possible to avoid n+1 django query here? If so, how?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have these models

```
class Thing1(MyModel):
    thing2 = models.OneToOneField(
        Thing2, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="super_pack"
    )
    some_id = models.IntegerField()


class Thing2(MyModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

class Thing3(MyModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thing2 = models.ForeignKey(
        Thing2,
        related_name="thing3s",
    )

class Thing4(MyModel):
    root_thing3 = models.OneToOneField(
        Thing3, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="my_related_name"
    )
    member_item_thing3s = models.ManyToManyField(
        Thing3,
        through="unimportant",
        related_name="important_related_name",
    )
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm working with a Django serializer. Already defined I have a queryset with prefetching.

As it stands, the following is performant:

```
all_thing1s: QuerySet[Thing1]
for thing1 in all_thing1s:
    first_thing3 = Thing1.thing2.thing3s.all()[0]
```

(from now on assume we are in the loop body)

which is not ideal, if there is always 1 `thing3` the schema shouldn't allow for many, but I can't change the schema at this time.)

**At this point I believe the ability to pre-fetch further has been broken because we have returned a Thing3 (`first_thing3`) and no longer have a query set to work with** At the start of this I thought Django magically used previous prefetches, I didn't realize that the filters etc. that you wanted to make use of the prefetches had to be chained to the prefetches.

But now I want to do:

```
thing4 = first_thing3.important_related_name.all()[0]
return thing4.root_thing3
```

(note: `first_thing3` and `root_thing3` share the same type but are not the same. And yes, again, the same silly assumption that there is a single `thing4` related to `first_thing3`)

But as per the bold text, I believe prefetching on the view's queryset is impossible.

I thought that perhaps you could be like

```
first_thing3 = Thing1.thing2.thing3s.all()[0]
query_set = Thing1.thing2.thing3s.filter(id=first_thing.id)
query_set.important_related_name[0]
...
```

But no because the addition of the filter would have to be account for in the original prefetch which is impossible, and the subsequent `important_related_name` only makes sense if it is on a single item anyway.

So this was about 8 hours of discovery for me. I think I have determined that it is impossible to prefetch using Django here and that n+1 is unavoidable.

Can a queryset by an aggregation?

I'm looking to confirm that avoiding n+1 is impossible (using built in Django functionality).